# Почему WCF приложение не может подключиться к самому себе?

Tags: wcf

С WCF мало работал. Только год назад курс прошел и отложил, сейчас вот вспоминаю и пытаюсь на практике применить.
Я написал простое тестовое приложение - client и server в одном флаконе.
Для client: текстовое поле чтобы указать адрес (типа "net.tcp://{address}:{port}") и нажать [подключиться].
Соответственно, для server: нажать [запустить WCF host].

У меня программа сама распознает префикс "net.tcp://" или "http://" и создает соответствущий binding...

Мне нужно было чтобы в app.config был самый минимум без указания реальных end points, сами end points будут браться из базы данных, в app.config мне нужны только bindings (пока только 2 binding-а - tcp.net и http).

Так вот, все работает. Также проверил под MONO (4.0 на последней Astra Linux) - тоже работает.

**Но(!)** почему-то работает **только если запущено два экземпляра приложения** (один в режиме host, другой как client к нему подключается).
А вот **если одно приложение**, в котором запущен host, то само к себе поключиться ну никак не получается!

В чем может быть дело?
Почему один экземпляр приложения не может быть одновременно и WCF host и WCF client?
Действительно ли есть такое ограничение? Либо же я что-то напутал, упустил?

Спасибо.

PS.
На всякий случай выложил код и config (без библиотек и проекта, только чтобы была понятна суть) - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V5PS4Bt-oL7T-2FWu3_l6pjYv25l6JOm?usp=sharing